# How can I find who call my method in a program?

Tags: java, eclipse, object, methods

I have a java class and it has some methods but they need some Objects from other classes.
there are many classes in this program ,and I want to know how can I find in Eclipse that Who(From which class) call my method and send my method objects?
I am working with Eclipse.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the method and click "Find references" or "Open call hierarchy".

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the method and press Ctrl + Shift + G. That should bring you the classes that call the method in question.

Comment: Actually all you have to do is click on the method, highlighting it is not necessary.  And it gives you all the places where the method is called from, which includes the classes but also the specific lines.  Very helpful.  I imagine the "find references" from other answers does the same thing, but I haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the method (or the name of the class for constructors calls) and select "Open Call hierarchy" from the context menu - you can also navigate the calls history.